# Running time of random pivot quicksort on random and sorted arrays

Tags: runtime-analysis, sorting, quicksort

I don't understand why I am getting the following execution times for the quicksort with a random pivot.

Times are in microseconds they are the average of five executions.

Random array:              9097
Sorted array:              4250
sorted backwards array:    4396

This doesn't make sense to me. It is obvious that the best execution time is for the sorted array, because you don't swap values, but why does the sorted backwards array have a similar execution time? Shouldn't it be more similar to the time obtained on a random array, or even bigger?

Here is my version of quicksort:

```
function sort(A[1], ..., A[n])
  if n ≤ 1, immediately return
  let x be a random number in 1, ..., n
  swap A[1] and A[x]
  i ← 2
  j ← n
  pivot ← A[1]
  while i ≤ j:
    while i ≤ n and A[i] < pivot: i ← i + 1
    while A[j] > pivot: j ← j - 1
    if i ≤ j: swap A[i] and A[j], i ← i + 1, j ← j - 1
  end while
  swap A[1] and A[j]
  sort(A[1], ..., A[j-1])
  sort(A[j+1], ... A[n])
end function
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the array $A$ just before the first two recursive calls.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks! very useful advice, I should have think in that before.

Comment: Consider answering your own question using a spoiler (see edit help).